# Why is my function receiving an error that it is not defined in this scope? I am simply trying to call the function and have it run as of right now

Tags: c

I am simply trying to have the createList function called and run, but I get an error that create list was not defined in this scope. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
typedef struct state {
  char trans[100];
  bool final;
  struct state *next;
} STATE;

STATE *stu = NULL;

stu = createList(stu, trans, states);

STATE* createList (STATE *stu, char trans, int states) {
    for (int i = states; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", i); /*ccode check*/
    }
    return stu;
}
```

Comment: Well, was it already defined _before_ the call? No, so the compiler has no idea what this function is, so it errors out.

Comment: Statements, like a function call, must appear inside a function.  Only declarations can appear outside of a function.  C compilers have a hard time with syntax errors like this so the diagnostic is not usually a very good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your C file, then there are two things to note:

1. You must declare the function (i.e. a prototype) *before* you can use it.
2. You cannot have executable code on the global level.

Try:

```
typedef struct state {
  char trans[100];
  bool final;
  struct state *next;
} STATE;

STATE *stu = NULL;

STATE* createList (STATE *stu, char trans, int states) {
    for (int i = states; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", i); /*ccode check*/
    }
    return stu;
}

int main (void)
{
    stu = createList(stu, trans, states);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I didn't give a prototype in this example because the complete function is defined before it's used, so the compiler knows all about it.

Comment: This makes more sense. I guess I am confused on what prototypes are. Do I have to have the function before main or is there a way to have it after main?

Comment: If you define the function (i.e. the body) after you use it, you must provide a prototype before you use it to tell the compiler about the function and its parameters. In my example I use the function after I have defined it so the compiler already knows about it and doesn't need a prototype. So you can have it after main and provide a prototype before main: `STATE* createList (STATE *stu, char trans, int states);` (note the `;`).

Comment: I understand now Thank you for the help.

Comment: How should I go about citing this as a source for the development of my code. Any outside assistance I receive is supposed to be documented.

Comment: I don't think that advice on the language (as specified in its standard) requires documentation for your code. Only assistance in developing the algorithms, data structures and the like would require so.

Comment: I agree with Paul on citing outside assistance, but if you want to do so, then you could give a URL to the question (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100766/why-is-my-function-receiving-an-error-that-it-is-not-defined-in-this-scope-i-am` or the answer (use the 'share' link to get `https://stackoverflow.com/a/56100827/11488965`), where the second number is your (@CharlesHartman) user number on SO — I replaced mine with yours. Maybe say who helped you (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100312/paul-ogilvie` — or [Paul Ogilvie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100312/paul-ogilvie)).